# How to Inspect iOS 13 and above? (on Chrome dev tools)

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, ios13, inspect

No devices appear at chrome inspect when i try to inspect iOS 13.2

I have tried remotedebug ios webkit adapter and it was working fine and able to see the device and inspect, now i cannot see the device after the new update of iOS 13 so any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The usual thing is to use Safari Web Inspector (in the Develop menu).

Comment: @matt i wanna use the developer tools on chrome not safari